# CQL data model to bypass secondary index issuee

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I have model which looks like

```
StateChange: 
    row_id
    group_name
    timestamp
    user_id
```

I aim to query as follows:

Query 1 = Find all state changes with row_id = X ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
Query 2 = Find all state changes with row_id = X and group_name = Y ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

Using my limited CQL knowledge, the only way to do so was to create 2 query tables one for each query mentioned above

For query 1:

```
CREATE TABLE state_change (
    row_id int,
    user_id int,
    group_name text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (row_id, timestamp)
)
```

For query 2:

```
CREATE TABLE state_change_by_group_name (
    row_id int,
    user_id int,
    group_name text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((row_id, group_name), timestamp)
)
```

This does solve the problem but I have duplicated data in Cassandra now.

Note: Creating an group_name index on table works but I cannot ORDER BY timestamp anymore as its is the secondary index now.

Looking for a solution which requires only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlo is correct in that your multiple table solution is the proper approach here.

> This does solve the problem but I have duplicated data in Cassandra now.
>
> ...
>   Looking for a solution which requires only one table.

Planet Cassandra recently posted an article on this topic: [Escaping From Disco-Era Data Modeling](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/escaping-from-disco-era-data-modeling/)

*(Full disclosure: I am the author)*

But two of the last paragraphs really address your point (especially, the last sentence):

> That is a very 1970′s way of thinking.  Relational database theory
>   originated at a time when disk space was expensive.  In 1975, some
>   vendors were selling disk space at a staggering eleven thousand
>   dollars per megabyte (depending on the vendor and model).  Even in
>   1980, if you wanted to buy a gigabyte’s worth of storage space, you
>   could still expect to spend around a million dollars.  Today (2014),
>   you can buy a terabyte drive for sixty bucks.  Disk space is cheap;
>   operation time is the expensive part.  And overuse of secondary
>   indexes will increase your operation time.
>
> Therefore, in Cassandra, you should take a query-based modeling
>   approach.  Essentially, (Patel, 2014) model your column families
>   according to how it makes sense to query your data.  This is a
>   departure from relational data modeling, where tables are built
>   according to how it makes sense to store the data.  **Often, query-based
>   modeling results in storage of redundant data** (and sometimes data that
>   is not dependent on its primary row key)**…and that’s ok**.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you're looking for does not exists. Two different queries requires two different tables (or at least a secondary index which creates a table under the hood). Denormalization is the norm in Cassandra so you should not think at data duplication as an anti-pattern -- indeed it's the suggested pattern

Comment: +1 for "Denormalization is the norm in Cassandra so you should not think at data duplication as an anti-pattern"